# OpenAi gym: Too many variables to unpack

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I an creating a model for theCartapole-v0 in google collab , but i am getting too many variable to unpack issue while training it

```
pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
!apt-get install x11-utils > /dev/null 2>&1
!pip install pyglet > /dev/null 2>&1
!apt-get install -y xvfb python-opengl > /dev/null 2>&1
!pip install gym pyvirtualdisplay > /dev/null 2>&1

import tensorflow as tf
import os
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display as ipythondisplay
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(400, 300))
display.start()

environment_name = 'CartPole-v0'
env = gym.make(environment_name)

episodes = 5
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
  state = env.reset()
  done = False
  score = 0

  while not done:
    prev_screen = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
    plt.imshow(prev_screen)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    n_state, reward , done , info = env.step(action)
    score += reward
  print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()

env.step(1)

log_path = os.path.join('Training','Logs')

env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose = 1 , tensorboard_log = log_path)

model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)
```

Giving error in the last line.

Comment: please [edit] your Question to include the full text of the error!

Answer (score 0):

For future proof you should note that all development of Gym has been moved to Gymnasium. Read more [here](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/classic_control/cart_pole/).

I did the following changes to make it work partially.

### Change environment to CartPole v1 since v0 is obsoleted

```py
environment_name = 'CartPole-v1'
```

### Do not call `step()` after got `done = True` from the environment. That is UB.

```py
#env.step(1)
```

### Change the rendering code

This works in `gym==0.23.1`:

```py
prev_screen = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
plt.imshow(prev_screen)
plt.show()
```

and this works in `gym==0.26.2`:

```py
env = gym.make(environment_name, render_mode='rgb_array')
```

### Final code that worked on my system

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display as ipythondisplay
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

def main():
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(400, 300))
    display.start()

    environment_name = 'CartPole-v1'
    env = gym.make(environment_name)

    episodes = 5
    for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
      state = env.reset()
      done = False
      score = 0

      while not done:
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward , done , info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        prev_screen = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
        plt.imshow(prev_screen)
        plt.show()
      print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
    env.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Note that I have no idea what you wanted to do after `env.close()` and I got some errors from those lines so you need to explain that first. I will edit my question afterwards. I hope this helps you.

Note that there is this warning:

> UserWarning: You provided an OpenAI Gym environment. We strongly recommend transitioning to Gymnasium environments. Stable-Baselines3 is automatically wrapping your environments in a compatibility layer, which could potentially cause issues.

It might be related to the error from these lines

```py
env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose = 1 , tensorboard_log = log_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of `gym` or `gymnasium` you are using, the agent-environment loop might differ. The reason why it states it needs to unpack too many values, is due to newer versions of `gym` and `gymnasium` in general using:

```py
n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
```

thus unpacking 5 values instead of 4. The `truncated` boolean states whether the environment had ended, but is applied when the reason for ending the environment is not because of the agent, but because of the environment. This could be the agent entering an invalid/faulty game state or exceeding a time/step limit within the environment. Either adjust your `env.step(action)` to unpack 5 values or downgrade `gym` (along with the environment) to a version supporting 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same piece of code in a YouTube tutorial and encountered the same error in the last line of code; `model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)`

The solution that worked for me was very simple; instead of `gym` use the new `gymnasium` library. I assume the error was caused by some deprecated elements in the `gym` library, which are not properly working with the new `stable_baselines3`.

I have included my code below; note that this only includes the lines of code required to run the model learning. This worked for me without any errors or warnings.

```
import os
import gymnasium
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

env_name = 'CartPole-v1'
log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')

env = gymnasium.make(env_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])  # Wrapping the environment -> vectorizing the environment
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)  # Creating the PPO model

model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)
```

Also, remember to use `CartPole-v1` instead of `CartPole-v0`; the gymnasium library will still identify `CartPole-v0`, but better to update to the new version of the CartPole problem.

Moreover, once updated to `gymnasium`, the code for taking a step in the environment must be rewritten as follows.

```
n_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action) 
done = terminated | truncated
```